# How can I export VBA code to text from de modules?

Tags: python, excel, vba, win32com

I'm trying to map all VBA codes I've in some excel in the office.

In my job, we have more than two hundred excel files, with a lot of macro in each. How can I extract the code text of some module?

I've see something like

```
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open("{}{}.xlsm".format(path, file), True, True)
for i in workbook.VBProject.VBComponents:
    print(i.Name)
```

Return

```
Plan1
Plan2
Main
Plan5
Plan3
Plan4
Sheet1
```

How can I get the VBA code in these Modules?

The solution could be in VBA or in Python

Comment: You could try checking out this [link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx)

Comment: http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm  has a function to export all of your modules

Comment: Something like this should help. Did it 2 years ago, on Excel 2013 - https://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-listing-all-procedures-in-all-modules/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution:

```
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open("{}{}.xlsm".format(path, file), True, True)

dict_modules = {}
for i in workbook.VBProject.VBComponents:
    name = i.name
    lines = workbook.VBProject.VBComponents(name).CodeModule.CountOfLines

    # To jump empty modules
    if lines == 0:
        pass
    else:
        text = workbook.VBProject.VBComponents(name).CodeModule.Lines(1,lines)
        dict_modules[name] = [text]

df = pd.DataFrame(dict_modules)
```

The DataFrame are returned with the modules name like the head of the table.
To look each text I found

```
# To get the full text
module_name = df["module_name"][0]
#To get by line
module_text_by_line = module_name.splitlines()
```

Thanks who tried help me.

Comment: That's great, but how do you get the text version of the Form's Designer file like you can in VB6 and VB.NET? Also, btw, I know this Q is Excel but since we're talking VBA, how about text version of an Access Report's Designer?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is close to what you are looking for?

```
Sub GEN_USE_Export_all_modules_from_Project()
' https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/60787-export-all-modules-in-current-project
     ' reference to extensibility library
Dim tday As String
tday = Date
Dim objMyProj As VBProject
Dim objVBComp As VBComponent
Dim destFolder as String

destFolder = "C:\Users\WHATEVER\Documents\Business\EXCEL NOTES\"
Set objMyProj = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject

tday = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(tday, "/", "-")

For Each objVBComp In objMyProj.VBComponents
    If objVBComp.Type = vbext_ct_StdModule Then
        objVBComp.Export destFolder & tday & " - " & objVBComp.name & ".bas"
    End If
Next
MsgBox ("Saved to " & destFolder)
End Sub
```

This will loop through your VBAProject (where this macro itself is stored), and will save the modules in a `.bas` file which you can open and go through.

Edit: You can replace `.bas` with `.txt` and it works, FYI.

Comment: But how can I get the text your code? Because a export the file module.

Comment: @user9438751 - Maybe I just misunderstood your question. If put put the above code in a VBA module, and run it, it'll export all the modules in that project, and save as `.bas` (or `.txt` if you replace that in the `objVBComp.Export "C:\...` line) to the folder you specify.

Comment: That's great, but how do you get the text version of the Form's Designer file like you can in VB6 and VB.NET?  Also, btw,  I know this Q is  Excel but since we're talking VBA, how about text version of Access Report's Designer?